# Trouble using Color Theif for background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a section that contains 4 boxes with images inside each one that take up the whole box. I am trying to use Color Thief to get the dominant color from each image, and set that as a filter over the image. Below are screenshots of how it currently looks, and what I am trying to achieve. Also below is the code pertaining to it and what I have tried so far. Any help would be very much appreciated!

How it looks now:
[image]

What I am trying to do:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="opinion">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="atable">
      <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => array('community', 'projects'),'posts_per_page' => 4,'post_parent' => 0, 'post_status' => array('publish'), 'orderby' => 'menu_order date')); ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="acell">
          <div class="contentbox">
            <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'issues'), 'large_size' );
            $url = $thumb['0']; ?>

            <ul class="slides">
              <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('issues') ?><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></li>
            </ul>

          <!-- <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('issues'); ?><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Color Thief js:

```
  var sourceImage = document.getElementById(".opinion .atable .acell .contentbox img");
  var colorThief = new ColorThief();
  colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
  document.getElementById(".opinion .atable .acell .contentbox:after").style.backgroundColor = "rgb('color')";
```

CSS:

```
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox {
position: relative;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific issue you are facing?

Comment: My code isn't working when trying to set the filters over the images. If you look at the screenshots, you can see in the second one there is a filter over the images. The filter needs to be of the dominant color of the image it is over.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're attempting to use the `getElementById` selector to get an element by class name which won't work, additionally that code would select every single image, not just a single image, which is what needs to be passed to Color Thief. Also, you need to pass the source of the image, not the element itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any advice on how I would be able to make it dynamic, so it works for each image? These images are going to change every time a new post is submitted, so it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: You would have to make an array out of the images and then loop through them. I also noticed that you are not defining the variable `color` it should be `var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);`